# Нет соединения с TCP сервером - Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, у меня имеется два приложение, одно - сервер, другое - клиент.

Я пытаюсь создать сервер с  IP адресом 127.0.0.1 на компьютере, где запускается сервер.Далее открываю клиент, где в поле "Server" ввожу `localhost` и номер порта.

Далее на другом компьютере, я открываю чат-клиент,в поле "Server" я ввожу: IP адрес того компьютера, где запустился сервер и тот же номер порта.

На втором компьютере соединения не происходит. Почему? Не понимаю...
Само qt-приложение работает, получается, что я путаюсь с адресами, по моему мнению...

Подскажите пожалуйста....

Как лучше показать код приложений?
Думаю ,что так:

*Сервер*:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/vilapm4sr1laimi/AAD5G0USlLf5UayQq2zHb9ZUa?dl=0

*Клиент*:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fx9jtzvtmeepzry/AABcDbvFU4ha4skHQP9AxK1la?dl=0

Или все таки ошибка в коде?

Comment: К localhost можно только с того же компьютера обратиться https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Comment: @jfs Пишу свой внешний IP даже, отключил брандмауэр. Все равно никак.

Comment: Попробуйте с помощью программы Wireshark проверить, идут ли пакеты.

Comment: Чтобы не мучиться, возьмите [сервер](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneserver-example.html) и [клиент](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-fortuneclient-example.html) из примеров Qt. Если окажется, что пример не работает, значит проблемы с сетевым соединением (возможно, что Вы вводите некорректный ip-адрес сервера). Если же пример заработает, то тогда будет иметь смысл разбираться с кодом.

Comment: @alexis031182 так и сделал, спасибо, провайдер закрыл порты, создал через Хомачи сеть и все заработало.